# echo variable but only when field not empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to complete a simple mySql query in php to echo a result, but I only want the echo to occur if there is data in the mySQL field that I am selecting from.

As such if the field in the database is empty I want the script to do nothing but close, and if the field is populated to echo the contents.

Code so far is as follows - this doesnt seem to be achieving me the desired result - if anyone could assist that would be great. I hope I have explained this well enough.

```
$lead_id = $_GET["lead_id"];

$connection = mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die ("Couldnt connect via user and password provided"); 



$db = mysql_select_db("database", $connection) or die ("Couldnt Connect to DB");



$query = "SELECT Result from database WHERE lead_id = $lead_id AND Result IS NOT NULL";



$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($connection); 

{
    echo $result;

}
```

Comment: I'd be more worried about fixing your gaping wide open [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability...

Comment: The syntax for a SQL select clause is `SELECT columns FROM table`.

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query); then while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo $row["Result"] ;}

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I will certainly fix the sql injection vulnerability. @AbhikChakraborty - I have tried your suggestion but appear to be getting a syntax error

Comment: Ignore that last comment - apologies

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - your suggestion worked perfectly - many thanks indeed

Answer (score 0):

If you're using $_GET, PHP will treat it as a string, however, you're using as an int in your query.  Try casting it as an int before your query.
`$lead_id = (int)$_GET["lead_id"];`

Comment: Also, make sure your datatype in MySQL is int.